# Change in TextBox VisualState when it disable

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How can I stop TextBox VisualState change when I change the IsEnabled property of a Textbox?

In other word, how can I make TextBox visually looks the same when I set it to disable and set it to enable?

Answer (score 0):

Most of things that aren't in the Property Page of the control visually are done through their `<Style>`, to edit the `<Style>` of the control just navigate the Document Outline (it's on the very left of Visual Studio)

> Document Outline > Find the TextBox > Right Click > Edit Template > Edit A Copy

At this point it will make a default  template for you for that particular TextBox, all you have to do is comment out all the StoryBoard elements of the `<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">` like so:

---

```XAML
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <!--
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                -->
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

Then

Set a TextBox to use this style like so:

```XAML
<TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="I have no idea when it's disabled now, since it doesn't look any different" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"></TextBox>
```